# search for http:// and https:// in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to prepand `http://` to every URL that doesn't begin with it, I used this:

```
if (val.search('http://') === -1) {
    val = 'http://' + val;  
}
```

The problem is that it appends `http://` to URLs that begin with `https//`
I want to ignore both `http://` and `https://`.

Comment: Try the 3rd response of this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links That's ok for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (val.indexOf('http://') === -1 && val.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
    val = 'http://' + val;
}
```

The `regex` way is:

```
if (!val.search(/^http[s]?:\/\//)){
    val = 'http://' + val;        
}
```

Comment: The `[]` is not necessary for a single character; neither is the `g` modifier

Comment: @ThiefMaster. You're right about the `g` I removed it a sec after I edited, but the `[]` makes it a lot more readable (IMO). don't you think so?

Comment: This could be improved a slight bit by adding the `i` modifier so that the search is not case-sensitive.

Comment: @bladnman, it only improve if you really need that modifier otherwise it cost you time and CPU for no good reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (val.indexOf('http://') === -1 && val.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
    val = 'http://' + val;
}
```

You could also use a regex:

```
if(!/^https?:\/\//.test(val)) {
    val = 'http://' + val;
}
```